# Какие примеры стилистически-морфологических приёмов имитации иностранных и нерусских акцентов, и каких именно, существуют в русском языке?

Tags: выражения, лексикон, идиомы

Какие примеры стилистически-морфологических приёмов имитации иностранных и нерусских акцентов, и каких именно, существуют в русском языке?

Ну, всякие такие приемы, как пример : "вах, дарагой !"... "Ти есть плёх сольдат"...

Вы можете привести любые неописанные здесь ранее примеры в любом количестве, хоть бы и один.

Comment: На сайтах stackoverflow обычно запрещены вопросы, подразумевающие ответы-списки. Вы как раз спрашиваете список всех приёмов имитации, на такой вопрос невозможно дать однозначный ответ, не проводя исследования.

Comment: да тут все запрещено.  Что еще с трудом можно спросить, чтобы мне было интересно. И тут полным-полно вопросов "на которые невозможно дать однозначный ответ", как выясняется. И заодно в последнее время - полный дефицит вопросов (или они куда-то деваются :>, появляясь), довольно странно :> 
Я не спрашиваю полный список - я интересуюсь неизвестными мне вариантами такого. :>

Comment: Для этого нам нужно знать известные (вам) варианты такого.

Comment: "На сайтах stackoverflow обычно "- кстать, где об этом вообще почитать ? :>
"для этого нам нужно знать" - ну вон парочка. :>

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: А попробуйте найти театральный форум и задать этот вопрос ещё и там. Актёрам тоже приходится акценты имитировать. Наверняка у них тоже есть интересные наблюдения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без претензий на полноту, просто что сейчас вспомнилось. Поставлю галочку "комьюнити вики", чтобы этот список могли править или дополнять все.

1. **Использование лексики, характерной для *русской* речи усреднённого иностранца из данной страны:**

   - Использование "вай", "вах", "дорогой" в речи грузин.
   - Относительно частое использование "таки" в речи одесситов (псевдоеврейский акцент);
   - "Ви" вместо "вы" для тех же одесситов;
2. **Использование лексики, характерной для *родной* речи имитируемого иностранца:**

   - "Майн либен, вы говорить с фройлен Светлана?" - видно, что немец.
   - "Си, сеньор!" - подходит для испанца.
3. **Учёт фонетических ограничений (и особенностей) родного языка иностранца:**

   - В китайском нет звука "р" (эризация не в счёт), в имитации меняем его на "л";
   - В китайском все слоги открытые (почти все, спасибо YellowSky что поправил), так что в имитации можно добавить гласных для удобства произношения и избавиться от неудобных сгустков согласных.
   - В грузинском согласные всегда твёрдые и нет звука "е", вместо него произносится жёсткий "э";
   - Для немецкого и испанского характерен среднемягкий звук "л", для имитации акцента мы это гиперболизируем и повсюду лепим сильномягкое "ль" ("ла" --> "ля"). Получается пародийно, но понятно;
   - Для немецкого также можно оглушать согласные в начале слова: "Та, та, топры фетчер! Што фам укодно?"
   - Грассирование для французов;
   - В испанском к словам, начинающихся с двух согласных, первая из которых "с", добавляется в начало звук "э";
   - В финском много удвоенных звуков, как согласных, так и гласных: "воккзаала";
   - У носителей самых разных языков есть проблемы с передачей русских звуков "щ" и "ч". В имитации можно усложнить эти звуки, чтобы показать, насколько неудобно их произносить: "борсчщ".
4. **Использование морфем, характерных для родного языка иностранца:**

   - "Нетто, нетто, ктоу говоритто?" - растянутые удвоенные согласные, окончание "-то", это итальянец;
   - "Вы входийт и вызывайт полиция? Я не нуждайт никакой полиция! Что ви ещё сделайт?" - видел такую имитацию, но затрудняюсь отнести её к какому-то конкретному языку.
5. **Имитация особенностей речи, связанных с национальной культурой иностранца.** Это уже имитация не акцента, а стиля. Но всё равно подходит:

   - Добавление "-сан" к именам в речи японцев;
   - Эмоциональность речи итальянцев (восклицания "Санта-Мария!", "Мадонна!");
   - Витиеватые метафоры, ассоциируемые с арабской речью: "кувшин моих мыслей показывает дно, о свет очей моих!"
6. **Неиспользование обязательных механизмов русского языка, трудных для овладения носителем другого языка:**

   - "Зачэм гаварищь? Я русский савсэм знаю, ащипка нэт пачти!" - проблемы со склонениями;
   - "Начальника сказала асфальта быть ровно." - проблемы с грамматическими родами и согласованием.

Comment: В китайском _не все_ слоги открытые, бывают и закрытые, которые оканчиваются на _-нь/-н_ ([n]/[ŋ]): напр. император Цинь Шихуанди (秦始皇帝), пиньинь Qín Shǐ Huáng-dì.

Comment: Отличный ответ :)

Comment: @YellowSky, верно, спасибо! Как-то я упустил, а ведь казалось бы такие простые слова - "жень", "лянг", да и "хуан тхиан" тоже...

Comment: Проблемы с р для евреев и французов, фрикативное г для украинцев...